# How to decode MJPEG frame into JPEG

Tags: objective-c, c, jpeg, mjpeg

I'm writing an iOS app to fetch motion jpeg stream via a tcp connection as in-memory data.

but the frame couldn't just save as a jpg file.

---

From what I googled, it seems like **MJPEG frame** doesn't have DHT like **JPEG** does,

but how to generate a **DHT** and put it into a mjpeg frame.

I also found few third-party libs like **libjpeg-turbo**, **ffmpeg** may accomplish that.

But most of the examples only show how to do it simply give an URL not in-memory data.

---

If you've done this in **C/Objective-C** before, hope you can tell me.

In the meantime, I'll keep searching for the answer.

and thanks for your time!

---

**UPDATE:**

Now I'm using [DFJPEGTurbo](https://github.com/kean/DFJPEGTurbo) and replace its libjpeg-turbo with the latest version.

It's easy to re-wrap mjpeg frame to a UIImage object.

It's the best way I've found, don't know if there's a better way.

and how can I do ***"ffmpeg -i {MJPEG_FILE} outputframe%d.jpg"*** programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already found the answer, which is quite easy to use.

Whomever need it, here it is :

[JPEGFixer](https://gist.github.com/gbrl0chn/1b1c3a480da57042a8fb63185d2d7250)

Answer (score 0):

Note that, this method only works if you're using **FFmpeg** and enabled bitstream-filters while compilation.

```sh
# this converts a MJPEG frame into a JPEG frame (adds a huffman table at the beginning.)
ffmpeg -i IN -bsf:v mjpeg2jpeg OUT
```